# Hibernate Utils failing to run in JSP Page

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

This is my first time using Hibernate and I am able to run everything on my local machine just fine, but when I deploy my website to my professor's tomcat web server I get the error message below. All I do in the UsersHelper constructor is get the session from SessionFactory in HibernateUtils.

Here are HibernateUtil: http://www.copypastecode.com/173998/

and UsersHelper: http://www.copypastecode.com/174002/

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /users.jsp at line 35

```
32:             try{
33:                  
34:                 
35:                 UsersHelper u = new UsersHelper();
36:                 
37:                 List<Users> userList = u.getAllUsers();
38:
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.myworkspace.hbconnect.HibernateUtil
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.users_jsp._jspService(users_jsp.java:281)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.myworkspace.hbconnect.HibernateUtil
    org.myworkspace.hbconnect.UsersHelper.<init>(UsersHelper.java:19)
    org.apache.jsp.users_jsp._jspService(users_jsp.java:241)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Just look at your stack trace, there goes something wrong during construction / initialization of UserHelper

Comment: Could you post your your org.myworkspace.hbconnect.HibernateUtil class.

Comment: I added link to the class files above.

Comment: Look more further down in the stacktrace. There's an `ExceptionInInitializerError` which in turn holds the *real* root cause. *That* contains the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.myworkspace.hbconnect.HibernateUtil
```

The mentioned class is missing in the runtime classpath. It must be in the runtime classpath as a standalone class file (*.class) or packaged in a JAR file (*.jar).

By default the webapp's `myWebapp/WEB-INF/lib` and `myWebapp/WEB-INF/classes` folders are covered by the runtime classpath.

Any 3rd party webapp-specific `JAR` files ought to be placed in `myWebapp/WEB-INF/lib`. Any webapp-specific classes (servlets, etc..) ought to be placed in `myWebapp/WEB-INF/classes`.

Check if you have place proper `.class` files and `.jar` when deploying.
Hope this helps.

Comment: All of my deployed files are in the correct places. The jar files used for hibernate are in myWebapp/WEB-INF/lib and my classes are in the class folder.